# What could be good position for the view showing the duration in the layout?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, interface-design, mobile, android, google-material-design

[image: layout image]

So I have song name, album name , album art at left side of the layout, and three views consisting duration of the song, overflow menu button and a playlist button on the right side of the layout. I want to have some suggestions about what could be the more better place for showing the duration while considering the fact that buttons should cover some area so that they can be more easy to use. In this layout the playlist button is very small in size, not easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little suggestion from here, if useful.. moved things a bit around and added a little duration bar, as an idea.

The exact time of where you are in the song could maybe also pop up/become visible when you push on the circle to scroll forth or back - like in netflix timer, if its within technical and budgetary reach, of course.

Also enlarged a little the icons so it could help on the usability side.

Sent one with a drop shadow effect and one without..

I like the setup a lot btw, it looks really nice and simple to manage and use.

Well hope the suggestions maybe help or inspire to an even better solution:)
Could be cool to see your end result when youre done, if you feel like sharing it:)

Regards
Reda

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your suggestions were fantastic. Really like the way you showed all the perspective. I just want to get clear about the suggestions you have made. First thing is, this is list of songs so from your side duration bar will be good thing for showing the last position where song was paused ? Will it be useful as we listen songs from begining always.

Comment: Or are you suggesting duration bar just for current playing song? Otherwise like really like the way the time was placed by you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback Dushyant, much appreciated:)

Comment: I think i would be most relevant to have the duration bar only on the actual playing track, then its also easier for the eye at a glance to see that it is that track playing and not the next or fifth having same duration bar on all of them, so yes i would say just one on the actual playing track.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and answers. Best of luck Reda, have all desires.

Answer (score 1):

As the length of the song is most relevant to the song, place the duration on the same baseline as the song title flush right. Its size and position do not change.
Directly below, is the playlist button placed flush right to align with the song duration.
The overflow button position is okay and remains unchanged.

In other words, the duration should appear on the same line after the song title with the playlist icon under the duration.

EDIT: If you incorporate the duration progress bar, put the duration at the end of the bar to show the length of the song.

Let active buttons grow to their optimal size for good human factors usability.

Comment: please confirm the illustration given by Reda about your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stan, great suggestion also.
Something like this?

[image]